# Finding matching phrases between two pieces of text?

Tags: php, string, recursion, logic

My objective is to find similar phrases from two pieces of text.

I know that common words will be a problem. For example, `and the` `we are the`. In that case, I think a filter will be necessary.

I want to know if this was a good approach? This uses recursion, if it finds a match, it sees if the next word is also a match, and continues on till there s no match.

```
  1. the cat is on the roof
  2. a man is on the stage

  A1 = [the, cat, is, on, the, roof]
  A2 = [a, man, is, on, the, stage]

  [the]: no match
  [cat]: no match
  [is]: match
  [is, on]: match
  [is, on, the]: match
  [is, on, the, roof]: no match
  [on]: match
  [on, the]: match
  [on, the, roof]: no match
  [the]: match
  [the, roof]: no match
  [roof]: no match
  -end-
```

Comment: you want us to advice on the approach, can you show the code, after the approach seems to be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search on Google showed me [this website](http://paulbutler.org/archives/a-simple-diff-algorithm-in-php/) containing the solution to your problem:

> It works by finding the longest sequence of words common to both
>   strings, and recursively finding the longest sequences of the
>   remainders of the string until the substrings have no words in common.
>   At this point it adds the remaining new words as an insertion and the
>   remaining old words as a deletion.